# generating UML class diagrams for drupal

Tags: php, drupal, uml, reverse-engineering

Hi I am using Drupal 6 for my final year project, I am required to create class diagrams for my website, so can you point to useful tools for this task.

Thank you

Comment: You gotta love arbitrary school requirements. I don't think I've seen anyone outside of school actually *use* UML.

Comment: @Greg I so agree with you, specially for Drupal since it's not even object oriented from the start. Amazingly though, the client I work for is demanding such documentation and I just find it to be irrelevant, but I have to provide it no matter what.

Answer (score 2):

Drupal is [not Object Oriented](http://drupal.org/node/547518), it won't easily documented with classes diagrams. So I don't expect any tools to be available to generate them. You can hoewever use any UML tools to create high level functional documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I was specifically studying the drupal way to write plugin. I wrote a [blog on this](http://miniim.blogspot.com/2014/12/drupal-plugin.html) accompanied by component diagrams. At first I prepared a component diagram for the menu subsystem as in the following,

[image]

Also there is a component diagram for the blog module,

[image: blog module component diagram]

Finally, I did not come up with any class diagram. But the component diagrams help to understand the internal working pretty well.

### Update

In new(8x) edition of drupal there are talks for class diagrams [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2168705#comment-9463035).

Answer (score 0):

Drupal uses the [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl) standard for documenting code. You can  generate the entire API of Drupal Core and all modules and themes you've installed in you Drupal application using doxygen. With regards to class diagrams, you will be able to generate class diagrams such as the one shown below. The example below uses [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) library but you don't need it to generate those images.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You could just try to use a reverse engineering tool to get a class diagram of the database tables that drupal uses. Should be good enough.

Comment: That is not a class diagramm, that would be an ER. And that might not work well with reverse engineering, because Drupal doesn't create explicit foreign keys/relations between tables, so you will just a have a larg(!) number of tables without any connections.